# How do you remove the default Drupal 7 administration menu?

Tags: 7, routes

I have disabled the "Toolbar" module, and cleared the cache; yet, it persists.

How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird, it just took time. I came back a few hours later and it was gone. Perhaps there are cache clearing issues in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

There's a permission in Drupal 7 labelled `Use the administration toolbar`.  Try unsetting this permission from the account.